# NPM custom registry interferes with fontawesome

Tags: windows, npm, font-awesome

I am running a React project that requires the configuration of a custom registry.

Doing:

`npm config set registry ...`

results in:

```
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="https://npm.fontawesome.com/"
```

This is despite the fact that root folder of project contains:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=XXX
```

This is happening in Windows 10 but was not happening on OSX or Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you solved that issue ? I am hitting the same error.